# Why in-app purchase doesn't show up in Payments Merchant Center?

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-pay

I have in App which has in-app purchase. I also integrated Google Analytics. I can see that in Google Analytics users purchased an item. But in the Payments Merchant Center only some appear? Normally they have to appear few minutes after purchase right?